# I want to run a macro in my personal macro workbook automatically

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Auto_Run
    If Weekday(Now()) =6 then
        Application.OnTime TimeValue(“15:15:00”), “DCSReport”
    End If
End sub
Sub DCSReport
   ‘My code
End sub
```

How do I get it to run every Friday at 3:15?

Comment: Note that this will only work if you never close Excel and never restart your computer. If Excel is closed or the Computer is shut down or in hibernate it will not run.

Comment: Correct, I will never shut down excel but this did not work for me. Do you know why this didn’t work?

Comment: Because it only will register the `.OnTime` if you run this code on a friday.

Comment: So how do I get it to run automatically on Friday?

Comment: Probably only with the Windows task scheduler. `.OnTime` can't do it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I think `OnTime` could, but you'd have to do some math based on today's weekday... e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444458/using-application-ontime-for-a-time-tomorrow.

Comment: And there is no other way excel can’t do it without the Windows task scheduler?

Comment: @bigben how would I get that to work every week?

Comment: You'd have `DCSReport` call `Auto_Run` to schedule a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

*Running VBA code at a specific time with Excel only is kind of risky, because many things can happen. Probably it is a simpler and better idea to do it through the task scheduler or through some kind of cloud service.*
 Anyway if you are willing to risk, here is a work-around:

- Dedicate a separate spreadsheet, named "Log" in order to log the weeks in which the code was run. To make the weeks unique, add the year - `Year(Now()) & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now())`
- Make some kind of an event in the workbook, which is not triggered often - E.g. `Workbook_AfterSave` could do the job
- Make a few checks in the Event, making sure that it would run at the specific time and day: `If Weekday(Now()) = vbFriday And Time > ("15:15:00") And notSavedThisWeek Then`

Code in the `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

    If Weekday(Now()) = vbFriday And Time > ("15:15:00") And notSavedThisWeek Then
        DCSReport
        LogThisAction
    End If

End Sub

Sub LogThisAction()

    With Worksheets("Log")
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(lastRow, 1) = weekYearNumber
    End With

End Sub

Function notSavedThisWeek() As Boolean

    With Worksheets("Log")
        Dim someRange As Range
        Set someRange = .Cells.Find(What:=weekYearNumber)
        notSavedThisWeek = CBool(Not someRange Is Nothing)
    End With

End Function

Function weekYearNumber()
    weekYearNumber = Year(Now()) & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now())
End Function

Sub DCSReport()
   Debug.Print "Code"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to approach running VBA macros automatically on a schedule. I find the simplest and easiest way to do it is with good old Windows Task Scheduler. You will need:

- A .VBS file which opens your workbook and starts your macro
- A Scheduled Task in Task Scheduler which executes that .VBS file using the CSCRIPT command

An example .VBS file might look like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\Location-Of\Your\Personal-Macro-Workbook.xlsm", 0, False)
xlApp.Run "NameOfYourMacro"
xlApp.Application.EnableEvents = False
xlBook.Close False
Set xlBook = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

Just create that in Notepad or whatever your preferred text editor is and save it as a .VBS file

Then in Windows Task Scheduler, create a basic task.

The name, Description, Trigger (schedule) are all up to you, but in "Action" you need to select "Start a Program", then just type "cscript" in the "Program/script" box, and in "Add arguments (Optional)" you put the full path and filename for your .VBS file. Making sure you surround that in Quotation marks.

Comment: How do you find the location of your personal macro workbook?

Comment: It's the location you saved it. If you have the VBA immediate window open,type:                 **?ThisWorkbook.Path**    and it will show it